# How to send paginated result as response after performing find operation in Mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, pagination, mongoose-schema

I have this query to display in a table on frontend so I used paginate which is working fine

```
tableSchema.statics.getn = (query, options) => {
  return mongoose.model(MODEL_NAME).paginate(query, options);
};
```

But when I am trying to perform search query then I am unable to perform paginate on that. Is there any way to send response as paginated form to all the searched queries
I tried following code

```
tableSchema.statics.search = query => {
  const Id = Number(query);
  const isNumeric = value => /^\d+$/.test(value);

  if (!isNumeric(query)) {
    if (query.includes("@")) {
      const regex = new RegExp(query, "i");
      return mongoose.model(MODEL_NAME).find({ "recipies.to": regex }).paginate(query);
    }
    return mongoose.model(MODEL_NAME).find({ "temp.name": query });
  }
  return mongoose.model(MODEL_NAME).find({ recipies: { Id } });
};
```

It is throwing me error that paginate is not a function. I tried storing find query result in object then performed paginate still it was not working.

I am using "mongoose-paginate-v2" for pagination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I think you missed to add pagination pluging in model section.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const mongoosePaginate = require('mongoose-paginate-v2');

const mySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  /* your schema definition */
});

mySchema.plugin(mongoosePaginate);

const myModel = mongoose.model('SampleModel', mySchema);

myModel.paginate().then({}); // Usage
```

You need to add `mongoosePaginate` in model as plugin.

```
let options = {
    sort: { createdOn: 1 },
    page: 1,
    limit: 10
};
ModelName.paginate({ 'recipies.to': 'value' }, options, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
       // Here you will get paginate array please console and check
       console.log(result);
    }
```

Comment: I have already added plugin I am facing error in this line 
`return mongoose.model(MODEL_NAME).find({ "recipies.to": regex }).paginate(query);`

Comment: Hi I edited answer and wrote pagination query.  Please check it may help. you dont need to add find().

Comment: Hey Thanks, actually I did that already myself, and yeah your solution is correct. Once again thanks a lot.